# How to manage large h5 files

Tags: python, h5py

I have been encountering this issue for a while. I have a h5 file with a dataset "ds", which consists of a matrix of size 170000x70000, float 16. Evidently, I cannot load all of this at once, but I do not need to. I only need to work with vectors of 170000x1 and filter out the elements that fulfill a condition. However, I am finding this to be very inefficient. I have tried to load it in chunks, like the example below, but this operation takes several minutes.

```
f=h5py.File(myfile, "r")
ds = f["ds"]
i=1000
for i in tqdm(range(0,170000,100)):
    chunk=ds[i:i+100,j]
    filtered_chunk =np.where(chunk>0)
```

Has any of you encountered this issue before? How can I tackle this?

Comment: It might be faster to load chunks of whole rows, and select the column in memory, e.g. `arr=ds[i:i+100, :]` and then `arr[:,j]`.  With the dataset stored in row major form, the `j`th column value is stored in widely spaced locations.   But I'm sure there's some sort of trade off between load speeds and indexing speeds.

Comment: Performance also depends on chunked storage, and the chunk shape. Ideally your chunk shape matches the I/O shape. So, if you want to read/write column wise (axis=1), create the dataset with `chunks=(170000, 1)`. Likewise, if you want to read/write row wise (axis=0), create the dataset with `chunks=(1, 70000)`.

Comment: I do not need several consecutive rows. Only some spare ones. I noticed though that going by row was much faster than going by column. I see the bottleneck now.
Would storing the ds as transposed help?

Comment: I suspect you either don't have chunked storage, or the chunk shape is larger in the row dimension.You can get the chunk shape with `f["ds"].chunks`. When chunked storage is used, _**the entire chunk is read when any element in a chunk is accessed**_. Review this link for details: [h5py Chunked Storage](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you read vectors of 170000x1. I think addresses your question

```
f=h5py.File(myfile, "r")
ds = f["ds"]
for cnt in range(ds.shape[1]):
    # get arr as a numpy array of shape (170000,1)
    arr=ds[:,cnt]  
    ...do something with arr
```

Comment: That was the first option, but I have to do this many times for different indices (that are not consecutive), and for several h5 files. This is super slow.